# Accelerometer/Motion Detection based applications for Android, iPhone and Window Phone 7 NON UI

Tags: cross-platform, mobile-phones, accelerometer

Is anyone here doing cross platform accelerator based development?

Are there cross-platform libraries/toolchains. I can see that Mono is available (sort of).

Does mono support the accelerometer on these devices reliably and consistently? I'm looking at the doing this kind of development and any advice in understanding architectural and tool limitations would be very welcome please.

Are there any alternatives to mono - I would have C would be the common otherwise?

I'm looking for commercial options also. Just to be clear this is for developing applications that use the motion detection capabilities of these devices, the GUI aspects are not so important at this stage.

**Edit: More information**

I'm looking at using the accelerometer to do some physics experiments and will be collecting data and projecting (the application bits) conclusions. Like all good science experiments I expect rubbish front ends until I have the theory correct.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of options for writing cross platform mobile applications.  If you want to write programs in Javascript, there are a few options, like Phonegap or Appcelerator Titanium.  Phonegap, from my knowledge, does not allow you to bind to native user interfaces of iPhone or Android, but Titanium does.  If you prefer Ruby, there is Rhomobile, which allows binding to the native user interfaces, as well as giving access to the core phone features.  I know GUI is not an issue for now, but for the future it might be something to take into consideration.  What is your language of choice?  There are options in many languages.

Comment: Thankyou. I don't have a language of choice as I'm really interested in getting something x-platform. I'm happy to move to any language as long as I can express the maths.

Comment: I am partial to Ruby, so I think Rhomobile Rhodes is an excellent tool for developing cross platform, mobile apps.  It supports most major mobile platforms.  If you like Javascript, then Phonegap has support for most platforms.